# How to OnNewIntent function inside SherlockFragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, onnewintent

In my application I am using **SherlockFragment** for **Sidenavigation menu** and as well as **Tab fragments**.

Here I got a position to use  **OnNewIntent** function inside `SherlockFragment`. But its returning an error like `"The method onNewIntent(Intent) of type classname must override or implement a supertype method"`.

code:

```
 public class MyClass extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the view from Twitter.xml
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity, container, false);

            return view;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);

        }
    }
```

So can any one suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Show you code you need to put @Override annotation above onNewIntent method

Comment: its asking remove @Override

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access onNewIntent inside fragment it is impossible onNewIntent is a part of activity so you need to place this method with override in you activity and access the intent via

```
getActivity().getIntent()
```

**You need to put onNewIntent inside a Activity**

```
public class MyClass extends SherlockActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
          //inside onNewIntent update your origional Intent by calling 
         setIntent(intent

    }
}
```

Now every call for getIntent() on this activity will give you the latest intent

Comment: its giving "The method onNewIntent(Intent) of type className must override" or implement a supertype method error and for quick fix.. remove @override its showing......

Comment: Put your onNewIntent in a SherlockActivity and it should work